# Возникает исключение System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. Как это исправить?

Tags: c#, xamarin, ftp

Необходимо скачать файл с FTP после нажатия кнопки,но при этом возникает такое исключение

```
button.Click += delegate {
   string path = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads;
   var filename = Path.Combine(path.ToString(), "myfile.txt");
  string ftpfullpath = "ftp://progsm@files.000webhost.com/public_html/1.txt";
  using (var request = new WebClient())
  {request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("progsm", "nubofo68");
 request.DownloadFile(ftpfullpath, filename); //возникает исключение System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request
```

Comment: Повторю то, что писал вам ранее - это не вся ошибка! Вы предоставили только заголовок, который гласит "Во время запроса WebClient произошло исключение". Смотрите более внимательней сам текст ошибки, без него мы вряд ли чем вам поможем.

Comment: Очень странно,я,кажется,ничего не поменяла,но теперь возникает другое исключение на том же месте
System.Net.WebException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>